# Is pattern matching preferred over reference or value equality?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I see a lot of examples on how to use pattern matching in C#7. It all looks good. However, I have a question, which I do not seem to be able to find an answer for.

Say you have the following expression:

```
if (a is null)
```

My question is: Is it preferred to use pattern matching instead of reference or value equality with C#7?

So instead of writing:

```
if (a == null)
```

or:

```
if (a.Equals(null))
```

or:

```
if (object.Equals(a, null))
```

I suspect the `a is null` generates something like the last expression. But would it in general be preferred to switch to pattern matching?

Correct me if I am wrong and this is a primarily opinion based question, but I could not seem to find a definitive answer that backed this up.

Comment: Definitely don't write `a.Equals(null)`, that will throw if `a` is `null`, not return `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following four code snippets:

```
// 1
var x = "";
var y = x is null;

// 2
var x = "";
var y = x.Equals(null);

// 3
var x = "";
var y = object.Equals(x, null);

// 4
var x = "";
var y = x == null;
```

The IL for these, respectively, is:

```
// 1
IL_0001: ldstr ""
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldnull
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
IL_000e: stloc.1

// 2
IL_0001: ldstr ""
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldnull
IL_0009: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
IL_000e: stloc.1

// 3 
IL_0001: ldstr ""
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldnull
IL_0009: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
IL_000e: stloc.1

// 4
IL_0001: ldstr ""
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldnull
IL_0009: ceq
IL_000b: stloc.1
```

As you can see, the first three result in near identical code. The `==` version uses `ceq` rather than `.Equals()`.

I'm guessing `ceq` is faster, and thus `x == null` is the fastest way of testing for `null`. Beyond that, it becomes a matter of preferred style.

Comment: The IL for #2 is not correct, that one uses `callvirt    System.String.Equals`.

Comment: Also, I think you should use Release mode when inspecting IL, that results in shorter code (no `stloc.0 ldloc.0`) and might give you a slightly better idea about the performance of the code.

Comment: in LINQPad 5 (.NET 4.6) both `== null` and `is null` result in exactly the same IL with optimizations on or off, but `== null` is still optimized a bit better when the left side can be evaluated at compile time like `default(string) == null`

Answer (score 1):

No matter if optimization is enabled, IL:

```
r = a is null;
IL_0004: ceq

r = a.Equals(null);
IL_0009: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object)

r = Equals(a, null);
IL_0011: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)

r = a == null;
IL_0019: ceq

r = a == default;
IL_001e: ceq

r = a == default(object);
IL_0023: ceq

r = ReferenceEquals(a, null);
IL_0028: ceq
```

I removed the repetitive noise for each expression:

```
IL_0002: ldloc.0
IL_0003: ldnull
      // ...
IL_0006: stloc.1
```

`a.Equals(null)` will throw an exception if `a` = `null`, so it is far from preferred.

Most probably `a == null` is used (short form, desired effect).

It should be noted that the operator `==` and method `object.Equals` can be overridden.

In the case that certain class have bad impacts with (significant performance degradation or worse - throws exception on) `a == null` then you can use for sure `ReferenceEquals(a, null)`.

`ReferenceEquals` always performs only the comparison of two objects and also uses `ceq`.
*Lack of `call` for `ReferenceEquals` means for me something à la `AggressiveInlining` (IL size: 5).*

Did you can use `is`? Of course you can.

But it look strange for me. You do not check the `a` type, rather you ask if `a` points to null.